# InvalidArgument error on Cloudfront createDistribution

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-js

**Node.js version**
v12.16.2

**SDK version number**
v2.727.0

When I try to create a new Cloudfront distribution through the API, I receive an error saying that MinTTL is a required field but, looking at the sdk docs, it says that the property is deprecated. When i put the MinTTL on the DefaultCacheBehaviour field, it says that ForwardedValues is required, which is another deprecated property. I am doing this with Typescript, so I also have type checking telling me that is all good. I am also specifying the latest API version on the constructor. Am i doing something wrong?

Returns

```
{
  message: "The parameter MinTTL is required.",
  code: "InvalidArgument",
  statusCode: 400,
}
```

```
  import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

  constructor() {
    this.cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront({
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: awsConfig.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
      },
      region: awsConfig.cloudfront.region,
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
      apiVersion: '2020-05-31',
    });
  }

  public createDistribution(param: ICreateDistributionParam) {
    const { domain, certificateArn } = param;

    const uniqueId = `${domain}${v1()}`;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.cloudfront.createDistribution(
        {
          DistributionConfig: {
            CallerReference: v1(),
            Enabled: true,
            Comment: `${domain} Production Distribution`,
            Aliases: {
              Quantity: 2,
              Items: [domain, `www.${domain}`],
            },
            Origins: {
              Quantity: 1,
              Items: [
                {
                  Id: uniqueId,
                  DomainName: awsConfig.ec2.prodLoadBalancer,
                  CustomOriginConfig: {
                    // custom origin config data
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
            ViewerCertificate: {
              ACMCertificateArn: certificateArn,
              CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: false,
              SSLSupportMethod: SSLSupportMethod.SNI_ONLY,
              MinimumProtocolVersion: MinimumProtocolVersion.TLSv1_2016,
            },
            DefaultCacheBehavior: {
              TargetOriginId: uniqueId,
              TrustedSigners: {
                Enabled: false,
                Quantity: 0,
              },
              AllowedMethods: {
                Quantity: 7,
                Items: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
              },
              ViewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
            },
            IsIPV6Enabled: true,
          },
        },
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          resolve(data);
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

The final object that I pass on the call is something like this:

```
{
  DistributionConfig: {
    CallerReference: "3e408c41-d8d6-11ea-b123-177f1e4dc4e3",
    Enabled: true,
    Comment: “teste.com.br Production Distribution",
    Aliases: {
      Quantity: 2,
      Items: [
        "teste.com.br",
        "www.teste.com.br",
      ],
    },
    Origins: {
      Quantity: 1,
      Items: [
        {
          Id: “teste.com.br3e408c40-d8d6-11ea-b123-177f1e4dc4e3",
          DomainName: “my-production-load-balancer-domain-name”,
          CustomOriginConfig: {
            HTTPSPort: 443,
            HTTPPort: 80,
            OriginProtocolPolicy: "http-only",
            OriginReadTimeout: 30,
            OriginKeepaliveTimeout: 5,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    ViewerCertificate: {
      ACMCertificateArn: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:522904521474:certificate/e221dfd8-72b7-4431-b9db-b460fdsds3be9",
      CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: false,
      SSLSupportMethod: "sni-only",
      MinimumProtocolVersion: "TLSv1.1_2016",
    },
    DefaultCacheBehavior: {
      TargetOriginId: “teste.com.br3e408c40-d8d6-11ea-b123-177f1e4dc4e3",
      TrustedSigners: {
        Enabled: false,
        Quantity: 0,
      },
      AllowedMethods: {
        Quantity: 7,
        Items: [
          "GET",
          "HEAD",
          "OPTIONS",
          "PUT",
          "PATCH",
          "POST",
          "DELETE",
        ],
      },
      ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https",
    },
    IsIPV6Enabled: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the argument value of the function `createDistribution`?

Comment: I put a new part on the question showing the call @jellycsc. I think you where referring to my own function right?

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant. I'm gonna reword. You passed a big object into `this.cloudfront.createDistribution`. I want to see what's actually there when populated with real values. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh ok i get it now my bad, i will make another edit on the post showing that. i will just edit some values because i don't know if they are sensitive information... i am kind of new to aws.

Comment: If you don't want to use the legacy parameter, you should instead specify `CachePolicyId` and/or `OriginRequestPolicyId`.

Comment: Ooo ok, i didn't know about policies, thank you so much @jellycsc